# Find which section of a convex polytope a point belongs to

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Consider the convex polytope in dimension $n$ with vertex set $V$ given by the origin and the $n$ points
$$
e_i=\begin{bmatrix}0,\dots,0,\underset{i\text{-th coordinate}}{1},0,\dots,0\end{bmatrix}, i\in\{1,\dots,n\}.
$$

Let $P$ be a point that lies inside the polytope. From every vertex $v\in V$, do the following:

1. Get the direction of the line passing through $v$ and $P$.
2. Extend such line from $P$ until the intersection with the boundary of the polytope.

The segments defined as above will split the polytope into $n+1$ sections.
[Here is a representation of this in 2D (where the sections are called $L_1$, $L_2$ and $L_3$).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNBeT.png)

Finally, consider another point $Q$ inside the polytope. I need an algorithm to determine which of the $n+1$ regions $Q$ belongs to.

[For instance, in this scenario I would like the algorithm to output $L_3$.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StWl0.png)

The biggest challenge is that, in order for this algorithm to be useful, it should have a complexity of at most $O(n\cdot\log n)$ **excluding any preliminary operations which does not need to be repeated as new input points come**. In a nutshell, I am ok spending any number of operations to compute useful quantities, but then the test for a single point **after** these operations are performed should be $O(n\cdot \log n)$ at most.

Comment: It is not quite clear to me how you "split". Pictures that concern, at best, only special cases are not definitions. After a formal definition of "split" is given, I think an algorithm would suggest itself.

Comment: line is ambiguous in $n>2.$ Besides, you should first also need a succinct definition of these regions first like : 
$$L_i = \{x\in\mathbb{R}\,\,\vert A_ix\leq b_i\}$$
etc.